# Ruby on Rails: seeds.rb and numbering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Some classmates and I have banded together to create a murder mystery game for a final project. It’s like a ‘choose-your-own-adventure’ game. Once the reader has read a piece of the story line, they are presented with multiple choice questions as to what they should do next. Depending on their response, this will lead to the next appropriate scene.

Our storyline is being stored in a model called Scene. If they’re on Scene 2.3, they choose answer 1, this will take them to Scene 3.1, and so on. We have parent_scene_id as well as child_scene_id. Therefore, Scene 2.3 is the parent_scene_id, and once they’ve chosen a response, that is now the child_scene_id which takes them to the new scene, yet again parent_scene_id. The story is split up into branches. A scene might take them off the main storyline for gathering evidence for example.

Example: Scene 2 (main branch), they choose the first option (this is now Scene 2.1). If they choose the second option from scene 2.1, this will take them to a tertiary branch called Scene 2.12. Once this is done, they are taken back to a main branch.

We’ve been instructed to use the seeds.rb file to get the appropriate numbering into the scenes. The URL pointing to these scenes will also have this same numbering system. We have to link it all together.

We’re really stumped on this portion, and we’d appreciate some help. If any further clarification is needed, please let me know and I will do my best. Thank you all so much.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure,  Is it indeed seeds.db rather than seeds.rb you are talking about here?

Comment: Just wanted to make sure,  Is it indeed seeds.db rather than seeds.rb you are talking about here? If you meant seeds.rb then this file acts as any standard ruby file and you have access to your application data. For example if you wanted to create a scene in your seeds.rb you could do a call like Scene.create(your_params). You can also find and update existing objects if you so need. You can then run rake db:seed to execute the file

Comment: Oh God yes, Julio it is in fact seeds.rb.

Comment: ok, in that case you can use the file as i had said in my coment above. Seeds.rb is meant to be used to get your app to a starting point in data. Just make the appropriate create/ update calls in the file in the file in the same fashion you'd be creating or updating objects in your other project files.

Comment: i'd also wrap everything in an ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do block to make sure that the updates / creates only persist if all the creates / updates happen. (this is assuming you are using activerecord as an orm.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an example with seeing some more details about your model.  It sounds like you have a HABTM join table for self-referencing, so, if I understand correctly, it's:

```
class Scene < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parent_scenes, 
    :class_name => :Scene, 
    :join_table => :habtm_scenes, 
    :foreign_key => :child_scene_id, 
    :association_foreign_key => :parent_scene_id

  has_and_belongs_to_many :child_scenes, 
    :class_name => :Scene, 
    :join_table => :habtm_scenes, 
    :foreign_key => :parent_scene_id, 
    :association_foreign_key => :child_scene_id
end
```

and your migration will have something like:

```
create_table :scene do |t|
  t.integer :major_branch
  t.integer :minor_branch
  t.timestamps
end
create_table :habtm_scenes do |t|
  t.references :child_scene_id
  t.references :parent_scene_id
  t.timestamps
end
```

So to seed it, all you need it a lot of rows of `create!`, followed by joining the associations:

`db/seeds.rb`:

```
Scene.transaction do
  scene2_1 = Scene.create!(:major_branch => 2, :minor_branch => 1)
  scene2_2 = Scene.create!(:major_branch => 2, :minor_branch => 2)
  scene2_3 = Scene.create!(:major_branch => 2, :minor_branch => 3)
  scene2_1.child_scenes << scene2_2, scene2_3
end
```

Once you're put all this together, just run `rake db:seed`. I highly recommend wrapping it in a transaction, as in the example above, so that if anything fails on the initial attempt, you can go back and fix the code knowing that when you run `rake db:seed` again, you are starting in a clean state.